# How to rename active-x Control textboxes that are grouped with shape after copying and pasting to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am putting together a Bar Bending Schedule for the Building Industry. I am new to excel vba and am doing my best but have stumbled across a problem that I am struggling to find a solution to.

I am working with the following objects in my project;

- Worksheet "BBS"
- Worksheet "Shapes"
- Userform "BBSForm"

I have shapes grouped with textboxes on the "Shapes" worksheet. Example shape is "L" which is an L-shaped Bar with 2 dimensions and hence 2 textboxes.

When the "L" shape is chosen on the userform and textbox dimensions are entered I click a button that submits the entry to the "BBS" worksheet. It copies the "Lgroup" from the shapes sheet and pastes it into the "BBS" sheet.

The problem occurs when I have 2 textboxes as once pasted they change name and I need to know their names so I can populate them with the dimensions.

I have the code below so far but the L shape doesn't work as "Forms.TextBox.2" doesn't exist, both textboxes in the group are "Forms.TextBox.1".

```
Sub ShapeSelectCopy()
    Dim CodeSh As String
    CodeSh = BBSForm.TextBoxShp.Value

    Worksheets("BBS").Activate
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5).Select
    Dim nextsh As Range
    Set nextsh = Selection

    Select Case CodeSh

    Case "S"

                Sheets("Shapes").Select
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 13")).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("BBS").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Dim newname As String
                newname = Sheets("BBS").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 0).Value
                Selection.Name = newname
                    With Selection
                                .Left = nextsh.Left + (nextsh.Width - Selection.Width) / 2
                                .Top = nextsh.Top + (nextsh.Height - Selection.Height) / 2
                    End With

            Dim shpG As Shape, shp As Shape
            Dim objOLE As OLEObject

                Set shpG = ActiveSheet.Shapes(newname)
                For Each shp In shpG.GroupItems
                Set objOLE = shp.OLEFormat.Object

            If objOLE.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then objOLE.Object.Value = BBSForm.TextBoxA.Value
            Next


    Case "L"
            Sheets("Shapes").Select
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 12")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("BBS").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Dim newname As String
            newname = Sheets("BBS").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 0).Value
            Selection.Name = newname
                With Selection
                            .Left = nextsh.Left + (nextsh.Width - Selection.Width) / 2
                            .Top = nextsh.Top + (nextsh.Height - Selection.Height) / 2
                End With

            Dim shpG As Shape, shp As Shape
            Dim objOLE As OLEObject

                Set shpG = ActiveSheet.Shapes(newname)
                For Each shp In shpG.GroupItems
                Set objOLE = shp.OLEFormat.Object

            If objOLE.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then objOLE.Object.Value = BBSForm.TextBoxA.Value
            If objOLE.progID = "Forms.TextBox.2" Then objOLE.Object.Value = BBSForm.TextBoxB.Value

            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the two textboxes arranged such that you know which is which based on their relative positions?  Or does it not matter which of the two values go in which textbox?

Comment: Yes tboxL1 takes dimension of longer leg of L shape and tbxL2 takes dimension of the shorter leg.

Comment: You could try modifying the code I posted to detect which textbox is (eg) above the other, then use that to determine which value they get.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Will try it tomorrow morning and let you know how I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factoring out some of the repeated code here's one approach:

```
Sub ShapeSelectCopy()

    Dim CodeSh As String
    Dim nextsh As Range
    Dim shtShapes As Worksheet, shtBBS As Worksheet
    Dim shpToCopy As String, val1, val2
    Dim tbCount As Long
    Dim shpG As ShapeRange, shp As Shape, pid

    Set shtShapes = Worksheets("Shapes")
    Set shtBBS = Worksheets("BBS")

    Set nextsh = shtBBS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5)

    shpToCopy = ""

    CodeSh = BBSForm.TextBoxShp.Value

    Select Case CodeSh
        Case "S"
            shpToCopy = "Group 13"
            val1 = BBSForm.TextBoxA.Value
            val2 = ""

        Case "L"
            shpToCopy = "Group 12"
            val1 = BBSForm.TextBoxA.Value
            val2 = BBSForm.TextBoxB.Value '<< edit to fix typo
    End Select

    If shpToCopy = "" Then Exit Sub 'exit if no shape to copy

    'copy the shape
    shtShapes.Shapes(shpToCopy).Copy
    shtBBS.Activate
    shtBBS.Paste
    Set shpG = Selection.ShapeRange

    'name and position
    With shpG
        .Name = shtBBS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value
        .Left = nextsh.Left + (nextsh.Width - shpG.Width) / 2
        .Top = nextsh.Top + (nextsh.Height - shpG.Height) / 2
    End With

    'populate textbox(es)
    tbCount = 0
    For Each shp In shpG.GroupItems
        On Error Resume Next
        pid = shp.OLEFormat.progID
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Debug.Print ">>>", pid
        If pid = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then
            tbCount = tbCount + 1
            If tbCount = 1 Then shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = val1
            If tbCount = 2 Then shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = val2
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim,
Worked!! I was getting the same dimension in the "L" shape textboxes but then realised that in Case "L" that val2 was set to TextBoxA value, changed it to TextBoxB value and now works a charm!!!
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you.  I edited that typo in my code.